# Unknown column 'whateverentity0_.end' in 'field list'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpql, dto

I have a Java project with MySQL database. I need to fetch entries from database and this is where I get the following error. Not sure why the end column is causing a problem. I checked several similar questions, but still can't see the solution in my case as the name of the column is pretty simple.

```
SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2021-09-08 14:30:49.190 ERROR 3308 --- [qtp345060426-21] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'whateverentity0_.end' in 'field list'
2021-09-08 14:30:49.219 ERROR 3308 --- [qtp345060426-21] conf.CommonErrorHandler                  : Request: uri=/test/information-entries raised org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Here is my entity class:

```
@Entity(name = "WhateverEntity")
@Table(name = "whatever_table_entry")
@Getter
@Setter
@Immutable
public class WhateverEntity{

  @Id
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "priority")
  private String priority;

  @Column(name = "created")
  private DateTime created = new DateTime();

  @Column(name = "modified")
  private DateTime modified = new DateTime();

  @Column(name = "start")
  private DateTime start = new DateTime();

  @Column(name = "end")
  private DateTime end = new DateTime();

  @Column(name = "notification_sent")
  private Date notificationSent;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "header_image_id")
  private ImageData image;

}
```

Here is the DTO class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Schema(name = "WhateverEntityDto.whateverentity")
public class WhateverEntityDto {

    @NotBlank
    private Long id;

    @Schema
    private ImageData headerImage;

    @Schema(example = "IMPORTANT")
    @NotBlank
    private String priority;

    @Schema
    @NotBlank
    private DateTime created;

    @Schema
    private DateTime modified;

    @Schema
    private DateTime start;

    @Schema
    private DateTime end;

    @Schema
    private Date notificationSent;
     
    public WhateverEntityDto(WhateverEntity whateverEntity) {
        this.id = whateverEntity.getId();
        this.headerImage = whateverEntity.getHeaderImage();
        this.priority = whateverEntity.getPriority();
        this.created = whateverEntity.getCreated();
        this.modified = whateverEntity.getModified();
        this.start = whateverEntity.getStart();
        this.end = whateverEntity.getEnd();
        this.notificationSent = whateverEntity.getNotificationSent();
    }

}
```

The database table whatever_table_entry looks like this:

```
id  bigint(20)  NO  PRI     auto_increment  
header_image_id bigint(20)  YES         
priority    int(11) NO          
created datetime    NO          
modified    datetime    YES             
start   datetime    YES MUL     
end datetime    YES MUL     
notification_sent   date    YES
```

Here is the repository:

```
public interface WhateverEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<WhateverEntity, Long> {
    @Query(value = "select we from WhateverEntity we")
    List<WhateverEntity> findActiveWhateverEntities(Long id, Date date);
}
```

and here controller's method where the error comes:

```
@GetMapping("/test/information-entries")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission()")
public @ResponseBody
WhateverEntityListDto getWhateverEntityEntries() {

List<WhateverEntity> whateverEntity = whateverEntityRepository.findActiveWhateverEntities(253L, new Date());
return new WhateverEntityListDto(whateverEntity.stream()
        .map(WhateverEntityDto::new)
        .collect(toList()));
```

}

Comment: Can you also post the code from which the error appears? E.g. is it a service that runs a query? If so please also post this code

Comment: @pleft  Added the controller's method from which the error appears

Comment: If I am not mistaken `END` and `START` are reserved keywords in MySQL. Not sure if this is the cause, but maybe it is worth trying to change the names and check again.

Comment: @JoãoDias that doesn't seem to be the case as I tried to change these names to something else

Comment: Please post the SQL query that is causing this error.